# Login page with Reactjs,nodejs and mariaDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mariadb

I have created a single page for login and registration using reactjs, nodejs and mariaDB. This is my first attempt. I was able to insert data to user table when user registered. Now I want to check whether user registered before when log in. if it is not I want to display error message as wrong combination.
This is the code I wrote for that in server side.

```
 app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
 
  
    const username= req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
     db.query(
        "SELECT * FROM  user WHERE username=? AND password=?",
        [username,password],
        (err,result)=>{
            if (err){
            res.send({err:err});
            }
            if(result.length>0){
                res.send(result);
            }else{
                res.send({message:"wrong combination"});
            }
        }
      );
      
    
  }
  );
```

This is the code I wrote in front end.

```
const login = () => {
    
      Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/login", {
    
        username:username,
        password:password,
      }).then((response) => {
        if(response.data.message){
          setLoginStatus(response.data.message);
        }
        else{
          setLoginStatus(response.data[0].username);
        }

      });
      };
```

but it doesn't work. plz help me to find the error

Comment: What should happen on the frontend when the backend goes into the `if (err){ res.send({err:err}); }` block?

Comment: @SimonCrane if there is an error in the statement then it send an error to the front end.

Comment: So there won't be a `response.data.message`

Comment: @SimonCrane I removed that part, but still doesn't work. Can you please give me some suggestions.